# Looking for quick tip regarding recursion

Tags: c#

If I have this code block here:

```
int n = 29; //or any number
    int i;
    int[] test = new int[100];
            while(n > 0 )
            {
              test[i++] = n % 2;
                n = n/2;
            }
```

and I want to make it recursive, what I thought of from the top of my head is pretty lame.

```
void Convert(int n)
{
   if(n < 1 )
     return;                  

   else
   {
      test[i++] = n % 2
      n = n/2;
      Convert(n);
   }   
}
```

I'm looking for the best way to write it recursively. Thanks in advance for the guidance :)

Comment: I see no reason to do this recursively. If your aim is getting familiar with the recursion concept i would suggest you taking a look at a Haskell language. Its very easy to get in and it exposes a lot of things related to recursion; "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good" is a wonderful guide for a beginner.

Comment: You could return test[] as the result of the method.

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser - you are correct sir, I want to get familiar with recursion. I don't intend to do the example code recursively as well. Thank you for that example as I haven't heard of it. Love the elephant :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll preface my answer by stating that this is not an ideal candidate for recursion, since it's not any easier to understand when done that way.  Nevertheless, here is one way to do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = Convert(new List<int>(), 192);
}

static List<int> Convert(List<int> bits, int n)
{
    if (n < 1)
    {
        return bits;
    }
    else
    {
        bits.Add(n % 2);
        return Convert(bits, n / 2);
    }
}
```

Recursion works best when you can maintain all of the state about the operation you're performing as part of the parameters to the recursive method.  For this method, the "state" of the operation includes the number we are currently trying to convert, plus the bits that have already been converted.

Passing the list of bits along with `n` prevents the need to declare the array and iterator variable outside of the recursive function.  switching to a `List` allows us to append the next bit onto the end of the bits we have created so far.  For the initial call to the recursive method, we have to "seed" the state by passing in an empty `List`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick explanation BJ!  Found a useful book, thanks to DiligentKeyPresser - " Learn You a Haskell for Great Good ". From first looking at it and reading some reviews it seems a decent intro to functional programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;

int Convert(int n)
{
    if(n < 1) return 0;
    else
    {
        test[i++] = Convert(n/2);
        return n % 2;
    }
}
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the bits of a supplied number in an array. Assuming array is of sufficient size:

```
void GetBits(int number, int index, int[] bits)
{
   if (number < 1 )
   {
       bits[index] = 0;
       return;
   }        
   bits[index] = number % 2;
   GetBits(number / 2, index + 1, bits);   
}
```

This method would be called with initial index = 0. Like, `GetBits(number, 0, bits)`.